# Generate a series of pseudo-random sequences to remove sequential bias

Tags: sequence, combinatorics, sequences, random

I have *n* things that are going to be tested by *t* testers. Each tester is subject to order bias (that is, they may give higher ratings to things they test earlier - or the reverse), so I want to eliminate that. One way to do that would be to generate a random testing sequence for each tester.

For example, with *n*=5, *m*=2:

```
 Tester 1         Tester 2
 4                2
 2                5
 5                4
 1                3 
 3                1
```

Notice that in this generated sequence however, both testers test thing 5 immediately after thing 2. Also, things 3 and 1 both appear towards the end of the testing, for both testers. This is sub-optimal.

My question: how can I generate an optimal set of sequences, maximising the chance of each thing appearing at every different position, and minimising the repetition of individual sequences.

Harder question: how much more optimal would that be than the naive (pseudo-)random generation? Can that be quantified?

This isn't a homework question, although it may sound like it :) (It's for a wine tasting...)

I really wasn't sure whether this should go in math.stackexchange, cs.stackexchange, or here. Ultimately I actually want to implement this, so...

Comment: Seems like a good statistical question for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) , not so sure it is (yet) a programming question.

Comment: Maybe. Problem is I don't know any stats. Last time I tried asking a question on MathOverflow I got an answer I simply didn't understand at all, and couldn't do anything with. I think probably my question is too easy for stats experts?